# How can I change the plot markers (on the top) in the given code to a special character?

Tags: plotting, marker

I am using this code

```
A := Cos[3 y] + (7 Sin[3 y])/( 2 y) + (-Cos[x] + Cos[2 y]) Csc[2 y] Sin[3 y];
B := (Cos[2 y] - Cos[x]) Csc[2 y] +  Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 y] + (2 - y Cos[x] Csc[2 y]) )^2];
F := (Cos[2 y] - Cos[x]) Csc[2 y] - Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 y] + (2 - y Cos[x] Csc[2 y]) )^2];

Manipulate[
 Module[{colorsDot = {Black, Green, White}, colorsLine = {   Orange  , Black,  Green}, pairs = Subsets[{" A ", " B ", " F "}, {2}], plt, pts}, 
  Show[Show[ plt = Plot[Evaluate[ToExpression[#[[1]]] /. x -> xv], {y, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> #[[2]], PlotPoints -> 1000],  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], #[[3]], 
        pts = Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plt],  pts /. {y_, x_?NumericQ} :> {y, 1.6}}], 
      PlotRangeClipping -> False,  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 10}, {Automatic, 20}}] & /@ 
    Transpose[{pairs, Subsets[colorsLine, {2}],  colorsDot}]]], {{xv, -5, x}, -5, -3, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}, TrackedSymbols :> True]
```

and I get this plot

[image]

**Question:**

> How can I change those points (on the top) to a special character, say "*", or anything else? I do not want to change the intersection points markers of the curves, only the ones on the top; something like this picture

[image]

I appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

A := Cos[3 y] + (7 Sin[3 y])/(2 y) +
   (-Cos[x] + Cos[2 y]) Csc[2 y] Sin[3 y];
B := (Cos[2 y] - Cos[x]) Csc[2 y] +
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 y] + (2 - y Cos[x] Csc[2 y]))^2];
F := (Cos[2 y] - Cos[x]) Csc[2 y] -
   Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 y] + (2 - y Cos[x] Csc[2 y]))^2];

Manipulate[
 Module[{
   colorsDot = {Black, Green, White},
   colorsLine = {Orange, Black, Green},
   pairs = Subsets[{" A ", " B ", " F "}, {2}],
   plt, pts},
  Show[
   Show[
      plt = Plot[Evaluate[ToExpression[#[[1]]] /. x -> xv],
        {y, 0, 3},
        PlotRange -> {0, 1.5},
        PlotStyle -> #[[2]],
        PlotPoints -> 1000],
      Graphics[{PointSize[Large], #[[3]], Point@
         (pts = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plt]),
        Text[Style["\[Star]", 20], {#[[1]], 1.6}] & /@ pts}],
      PlotRangeClipping -> False,
      ImagePadding ->
       {{Automatic, 10}, {Automatic, 20}}] & /@

        Transpose[{pairs, Subsets[colorsLine, {2}],
      colorsDot}]]],
 {{xv, -5, x}, -5, -3, 0.01, Appearance -> "Open"},
 TrackedSymbols :> True]
```

[image]